# Bitmap(Int32, Int32, PixelFormat) throws ArgumentException

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to get a part of a screenshot but unfortunately I am getting `ArgumentException` when I am creating `Bitmap`. Here's a code :

```
public Bitmap bp(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
   Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
   using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
   {
      g.CopyFromScreen(x, y, 0, 0, bitmap.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
   }
   return bitmap;
}
```

When it's trying to make bitmap it throws:

> ArgumentException. "Parameter isn't valid".

Can any one help to handle this ?

I Call this Function :

```
Bitmap ln = bp(Convert.ToInt32(textBox55.Text),     
 Convert.ToInt32(textBox56.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox59.Text) -  
 Convert.ToInt32(textBox55.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox56.Text) - 
 Convert.ToInt32(textBox60.Text));
```

I am getting Parameters from `TextBox`

Comment: can you share park of the stacktrace?

Comment: How are you calling this method ?? are you passing valid parameters ?? can you post complete stacktrace ??

Comment: What numbers (if any) are in he Textboxes? How large are they? Bitmaps can't be arbitrarily large..

Comment: I am Clicking on Screen and getting coordinates of of Mouse Click. for example in textbox1 = X coordinate and textBox2 = Y coordinate.

Comment: Please check your parameter value. What you passing in parameter?

Answer (score -1):

You must be passing width and height as 0 to this method.

Width and height must be greater than 0.